# Forming vectors from the same assigned value

Tags: matlab, analysis

I've got a bunch of values that are all assigned the same variable due to running through a for loop several times, so for example:

```
d = 3.44434
d = 2.4444
d = 2.7777
```

How do I put them all into a vector?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of values beforehand, you can speed things up (if there are several elements) by **preallocating**.

#### Code

```
num_elements = 10;
vector = zeros(num_elements,1);
for i = 1:num_elements
   vector(i) = SomeFunction();
end
```

If you **don't** know the number of elements before running the loop,

#### Code

```
vector = [];
some_condition = true;
while some_condition == true
   vector(end+1) = SomeFunction();
   some_condition = SomeConditionFunction();
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a loop for your operations, use Jacob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789557/forming-vectors-from-the-same-assigned-value-in-matlab/2789634#2789634). Otherwise, if you're doing a relatively simple operation, you may be able to vectorize. For example:

```
x=1:10; % input vector
rootofx=sqrt(x); % output vector
```

The ./ .* and .^ operators are useful if you want to perform element-wise operations.